# Django CreateView autofill custom user

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

I want to use Django's GCBV [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) to autofill the `created_by` field on my model with the current user. The official docs have a [good example here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) but I'm using a custom user model and having trouble making it work.

Here's my current setup:

```
# models.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

# views.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.get_user_model()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

However upon form submission I get the error:

```
AttributeError at /posts/new/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get_user_model'
```

If I don't try to auto-include the user the form works fine which is why I don't believe the problem is with my custom user config. Here's what that code looks like:

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name', 'created_by']
```

Comment: Can you share how you've set up the custom user?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the issue since if I just set the `created_by` field in `AuthorCreate` and remove the `def from_valid...` code then the form works, it just requires I manually select the user. But I'll post my custom user config in a sec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the particular error you're seeing should be able to use the self.request.user directly as shown in the example you linked. (Assuming the custom user model is correctly set up.)

```
form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
```

The get_user_model function is generally used like this to access the User class:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

generally in place of

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: Yes you're right. I was confusing `User` with the `user` on the request. Thanks for your help!